# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1082-1084: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python

this is my first time using python, im trying to make CT asset to CSV

this is my code

tsv.py

```
    def write(self, data):
        """
        Write list to TSV

        :param list data: Decoded list to write on TSV file
        """

        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("./{0}".format(self.path)), exist_ok=True)
        self.tsv = open(self.path, "w", newline="\r\n")

        self.header = "\t".join(i for i in data[0]) + "\n"
        self.types = "\t".join(i for i in data[1]) + "\n"
        self.rows = "\n".join("\t".join(l) for l in data[2:]) + "\n"

        self.tsv.write(self.header + self.types + self.rows)
        if self.verbose:
            print("\nTSV write to \"{0}\" complete!\n".format(self.path))
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
line 48, in write
    self.tsv.write(self.header + self.types + self.rows)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1082-1084: character maps to <undefined>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: ty for the link you suggest to me, but it still doesnt help me to understand how to fix this

Comment: Find out the codes at that position. If necessary, read and print one line at a time until this error occurs. [Edit] your question and add what you found. It looks like this `asset` library blindly assumes the input file is using the standard Latin-1 codepage, but apparently that is not the case.

Comment: More probably `asset` reads in Unicode and the OP's terminal only supports their current code page. But without seeing what the problematic bytes in the input file are, all we can offer is loose speculation. Can you add a `try:` before the `print` statements and `except UnicodeEncodeError as e: print('error {0}: {1!r}'.format(e, data[1080:1087]])); raise(e)`

Comment: Which parts of the meta post do you find unclear? Do you still have trouble understanding the error message?

Comment: The error message indicates that you are using Python 3 and that it is trying to write text using the Windows code page 1252 encoding.  The actual error is that your data contains a character which does not exist in this encoding. I would have expected Python 3 to write UTF-8 but it's not; perhaps you can add `encoding="utf-8"` to the `open` call if that is in fact what you want? I.e. `self.tsv = open(self.path, "w", newline="\r\n", encoding="utf-8")`

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that you are using Python 3 and that it is trying to write text using the Windows code page 1252 encoding.  The actual error is that your data contains a character which does not exist in this encoding. I would have expected Python 3 to write UTF-8 but it's not; perhaps you can add `encoding="utf-8"` to the `open` call if that is in fact what you want?

```
self.tsv = open(self.path, "w", newline="\r\n", encoding="utf-8")
```

If your script works reliably for you, there is no real need to change it; but reinventing CSV/TSV writing is not a good idea -- you are ignoring several corner cases which the existing [`csv` module in the Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) already handles.

```
import csv
import logging

class whatever: ...

    def write(self, data):
        """
        Write list to TSV

        :param list data: Decoded list to write on TSV file
        """

        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname("./{0}".format(self.path)), exist_ok=True)
        with open(self.path, "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as tsv:
            writer = csv.writer(tsv, delimiter="\t")
            writer.writerows(data)

        logging.info('TSV write to "%s" complete!', self.path))
```

Your code also lacks `self.tsv.close()` which the above code doesn't need because the `with` handles that transparently.

Additionally, I switched to [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) for the informational message. It similarly offers a canned solution which already knows how to write messages to standard error instead of standard output etc (though you might want to look at `logging.basicConfig` to set up the formatting to your liking -- I usually put `logging.basicConfig('%(module)s:%(message)s')` for simple command-line utilities).